# How to run multiple R scripts simultaneously?

Tags: r, bash

I would like to run all the R script (script1.R, script2.R, ...) stored in a directory (~/Sims). Moreover I would like that each script run in a separate terminal. The os I'm using is OS X 10.9.5.

I used a bash script with the following commands:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=~/Sims/*.R
for f in $FILES 
do 
 xterm -e bash -c "R --vanilla < $f; exec bash" &
done
```

1. I would like to find an alternative for xterm (given that under os x require to install the package X11 and on some machine I can't install it) that it is part of os x (like the Terminal app)
2. I would like to not exit from the R environment at the end of the R script

Comment: This is not an R problem so much as it is a scripting problem. There are lots of ways to do this in the shell. You might have more luck looking for examples of how to run scripts in the background.

Comment: You may want take a look at GNU Screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will mimic your `xterm` configuration but use new Terminal.app sessions instead:

```
for f in *.R
do
  osascript -e "tell app \"Terminal\" to do script \"R --vanilla < /FULL/PATH/TO/${f}\""
done
```

As far as keeping the R session alive, I'm not sure that's possible.